# How to dynamic formating Enum label at runtime

Tags: java, string, enums, format

I created a custom `enum` type for error handling with two variables code and label, and I would like the value of the label property of the enum to be formatted at runtime using `String.format(key, value)`.

```
public enum CustomErrorEnum {

    MISSING_VALUE1("CODE1","the label %s is missing"),
    WRONG_VALUE1("CODE2","the label %s is wrong");
    
    private String code;
    private String label;
    
    CustomErrorEnum(String code, String label)
    {
        this.code = code;
        this.label = label;
    }
}
```

I am trying to customize the log by specifying the reason and the value that throw the exception.

For example, when the user field a wrong, for example, I need the output to be:

```
W001, The value *2026-13-13* is wrong
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would introduce a method on `enum` to provide a formatted message based on the arguments provided:

```java
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public enum CustomErrorEnum {

    MISSING_VALUE1("CODE1","the label %s is missing"),
    WRONG_VALUE1("CODE2","the label %s is wrong");

    private final String code;
    private final String message;

    public final String format(Object... args) {
        return String.format(message, args);
    }
}
```

```java
System.out.println(CustomErrorEnum.WRONG_VALUE1.format("*2026-13-13*"));
```

> ```
> the label *2026-13-13* is wrong
> ```

If you use Java 15+ you can use `message.formatted(args)` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [String.format](https://self-learning-java-tutorial.blogspot.com/2014/06/format-string-format-object-args.html) method.

```
public static String finalMsg(final CustomErrorEnum customErrorEnum, Object... args) {
        final String formattedMsg = String.format(customErrorEnum.label, args);
        return customErrorEnum.code + "," + formattedMsg;
    }
```

Complete applicaiton is given below.

```
public class App {

    private static enum CustomErrorEnum {
        MISSING_VALUE1("CODE1", "the label %s is missing"), WRONG_VALUE1("CODE2", "the label %s is wrong");

        private String code;
        private String label;

        CustomErrorEnum(String code, String label) {
            this.code = code;
            this.label = label;
        }

    }

    public static String finalMsg(final CustomErrorEnum customErrorEnum, Object... args) {
        final String formattedMsg = String.format(customErrorEnum.label, args);
        return customErrorEnum.code + "," + formattedMsg;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(finalMsg(CustomErrorEnum.MISSING_VALUE1, "city"));
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

For adding Values inside a String you can do:

```
String error = "W001, The Value " + variable + " is wrong"
```

In combination with your enum, if you get a String than create a new one like

```
String error = yourString.subString(index1,index2) + variables + sourString.subString(index3, index4);
```